# Deleting a Microsoft 365 E5 Developer Subscription

Tags: office365, microsoft365

Does anyone know if it's possible to delete a Microsoft 365 E5 Developer Subscription?

I've haven't been using it but somehow it keeps getting renewed, so I was wondering if I could delete it or I have to reach for MS's support.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Activity Microsoft 365 E5 Developer Subscription will renew itself and if you want you can remove it, the best way to uninstall is to use the Microsoft Support and Recovery Tool(SaRA) with the following [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-the-microsoft-support-and-recovery-assistant-e90bb691-c2a7-4697-a94f-88836856c72f), download and install it and open the application and follow the steps below.

1. Click on Office and Click Next
2. From the given options Choose the option that says "I have Office installed, but I'm having trouble uninstalling it" and click Next
3. It'll ask you if the machine you are using is the affected machine Click on "Yes"(assuming that you are using the same machine) and Click Next
4. It'll request you to "Select the Office Version you want to remove", below that you'll be able to see a drop down which will have "office versions" written on it, click the drop down and select the version that you have, if you are not sure choose "All the above versions (Please be patient, may take several minutes)" and click Next
5. The App might request you to restart the SaRA app click on restart, let the process complete
6. Once it has completed uninstalling please restart your system.

The Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant(SaRA) Application is not limited to Microsoft 365 E5 Developer Subscription you can use it to uninstall other office versions too and solve lot of issues which are related to Windows and other Microsoft Apps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to SaRa tool